# how can I design a planetary gearbox?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

How can I design a planetary gearbox with 1:20 ratio that the planets do not interfere with each other?

Comment: Why not do it in two stages? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fAtXe7yJolE

Answer (score 1):

Offset the planet gears longitudinally from each other.

However this can create a twisting force on the sun gear or the ring gear as torque is transferred.